# Java Apache HTTP Async Client issue with redirect https url

Tags: java, redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am getting General SSLEngine problem when try to make call to url which contains url with https protocol in redirection.

I am using [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/) version 4.1

e.g.:
main url https://example.com redirects to https://example.net

Working fine in case of HTTP.

I tried using:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {

      @Override
      public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
      sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().useTLS().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle error
    }
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient =
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(HttpClientUtils.configForClient)
            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
            .setSSLContext(sslContext).setRedirectStrategy(LaxRedirectStrategy.INSTANCE).build();
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: General SSLEngine exception